# Problemas, Objetos colidindo de maneira errada Unity3d

Tags: unity3d

Estou com um problema que ainda não consegui encontrar a solução:

Estou tentando terminar um projeto com o Unity, um simples jogo de corrida em 2D, onde a câmera fica estática vista de cima e os objetos descem pela gravidade. Esta funcionalidade **quase completa**, os scripts estão funcionando corretamente, o carro e o Power Up se movimentando como deveriam, mas no momento em que o dinheiro passa pelo carro está o problema, ao invés de colidir e desaparecer somando a pontuação, o carro está sendo arrastado com ele.

Estou mandando duas capturas de telas do **Inspector** do carro e do dinheiro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link da vídeo aula deste projeto que estou baseando-me.](https://youtu.be/wFGwk7edyYA)

Ao final desta aula, o autor refere-se em marcar Is Kinematic para resolver a colisão dos objetos "carro" , "dinheiro".

Comment: Primeira coisa o seu objeto dinheiro deve ser trigger pois quando bater no carro nao reduzira a velocidade dele
Se possivel manda um print do codigo pra ve se o problema esta la

Comment: Senhores obrigado pelas respostas. Mas ainda não consegui resolver esse pequeno grande detalhe. Vou enviar um link de uma video aula de onde estou seguindo. Quase no final Nils fala que para resolver essa colisão é apenas marcar a opção " is Kinematic " mas comigo isso não funciona https://youtu.be/wFGwk7edyYA

Comment: Poderia postar um comentário para o Nils com o link da sua pergunta aqui, acredito que ele não tenha visto.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Jhonny Summer

Te aconselho a usar OnTriggerEnter2D, caso o dinheiro não afete nada na direção do carro ao colidir, Quando é usado o Trigger ele não atribui os efeitos da física como dois corpos se chocando =D, espero que ajuda, faca a comparação dentro disso -> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

Não esqueça, o objeto que está vinculado a script que tem o método OnTriggerEnter2D deve estar com o colisor "On trigger" Marcado.

Qualquer duvida estamos ai.

Answer (score 0):

Não consigo visualizar as imagens Jhonny mas vou dar um palpite considerando que todo seu sistema realmente é baseado em gravidade.

Neste caso vc deve ter um Rigidbody2D em todos os seus objetos. O atributo "massa" do seu objeto de dinheiro deve estar muito grande de forma a causar influência no carrinho quando colide, já no PowerUp ela deve estar muito inferior e por isso não chega a causar um deslocamento antes do objeto ser destruido.

Algumas coisas que vc pode revisar pra tentar corrigir:

1: Compare os valores dos atributos do rigidbody (principalmente: "Mass", "Gravity scale" e "Is Kinematic" ) e tente deixar o seu objeto de dinheiro igual ao de PowerUp.

2: Compare os atributos dos colisores (principalmente: "Is Trigger") e deixe os de dinheiro iguais aos do PowerUp...

3: Verifique como/quando o PowerUp é destruido no script de comportamento dele e se o dinheiro possui uma chamada para ser destruido também (pode ser que como ele não está sendo destruido ao colidir ele cai sobre o carrinho e fica ali somando à massa e à influência de gravidade que o carro sofre causando o efeito indesejado).

Answer (score 0):

Tenta integrar não só o Rigidbody2D mas desativar o objeto a ser colidido e caso tenha alguma transação com sprite ativa o animator e desativa o objeto ou o destroi (no caso a destruição é mais aconselhada pra consumir menos memoria).